# Psexec command unusual behavior

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2008, remote-access, psexec

I am running below code:

**master.bat:**

```
@echo off
call :Commands >D:\Test\log.txt
exit /b

:Commands
@echo off
setlocal
for /F "delims= " %%i in (D:\Test\servers.txt) do ( psexec \\%%i -c D:\Test\script.bat )
exit
```

Where...

**servers.txt:**

```
server1 
server2
server3
```

**script.bat:**

```
taskkill /F /IM notepad.exe
taskkill /F /IM firefox.exe
taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe
```

I am running **master.bat** putting on server2, Everything is working fine but the problem I am facing here is: I verified that on local server2 also script run successfully but there is no log for local server2 coming in **log.txt** file as below while log for server1 and server3 are coming as expected:

**log.txt:**

```
C:\Windows\system32>taskkill /F /IM notepad.exe 
SUCCESS: The process "notepad.exe" with PID 8932 has been terminated.
C:\Windows\system32>taskkill /F /IM firefox.exe 
SUCCESS: The process "firefox.exe" with PID 7580 has been terminated.
C:\Windows\system32>taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe 
SUCCESS: The process "explorer.exe" with PID 8932 has been terminated.

C:\Windows\system32>taskkill /F /IM notepad.exe 
SUCCESS: The process "notepad.exe" with PID 7586 has been terminated.
C:\Windows\system32>taskkill /F /IM firefox.exe
SUCCESS: The process "firefox.exe" with PID 8032 has been terminated.
C:\Windows\system32>taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe  
SUCCESS: The process "explorer.exe" with PID 7530 has been terminated.
```

Why is there this unusual behavior with PsExec command ??

**EDIT :cmd screen output on server2 after running master.bat:**

I crossed checked again, script ran on server2 successfully and its visible from cmd screen also, but still that didn't come in log for server2. I tested with  -accepteula option also but no change in behavior.I am putting here my cmd screen output:

```
PsExec v2.0 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2013 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Starting D:\Test\script.bat on server1...
script.bat existed on server1 with error code 0.

PsExec v2.0 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2013 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

D:\Test\script.bat existed with error code 0.

PsExec v2.0 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2013 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Starting D:\Test\script.bat on server3...
script.bat existed on server3 with error code 0.
```

Comment: Have you checked event logs on server2 to confirm if it attempted to execute the remote psexec or from where you executed the batch script.

Comment: Have you ran PsExec at least once on Server2? If not, you'll have to run it and accept the eula. Alternately, you can add the /accepteula switch to your PsExec call.

Comment: @Matt..I crossed checked again, script run on server2 successfully and its visible from cmd screen also, but still that didn't come in log for server2. I tested with  -accepteula option also but no change in behavior.I have put my cmd screen output in **EDIT** above.

Comment: @Chelsea..Yes..I checked the event logs on server2, the script.bat ran successfully on server2 and the same is clear from the cmd screen output on server2 mentioned in above **EDIT**.